# Is let keyword of javascript not supported in apigee

Tags: apigee

When I m trying to declare a variable using let keyword I am getting this error,

Error creating object
Compilation of JavaScript jsc://ExtractPathVariableOrQueryParam.js failed with error:Compilation error: missing ; before statement (JSC_ExtractPathVariableOrQueryParam#7). Line:7, column:23. Source is:let resourceId = context.getVariable('proxy.pathsuffix').substring(resourceIdPath.length).split('/')[0];. Context Revision:10;APIProxy:flow-something;Organization:asif-nonprod;Environment:pre-prod .

my code snippet of javascript is

```
extractResourceId(resourceIdLocation, resourceIdPath);

function extractResourceId(resourceIdLocation, resourceIdPath) {
if (resourceIdLocation == "PATH_VARIABLE") {
let resourceId = context.getVariable('proxy.pathsuffix').substring(resourceIdPath.length).split('/')[0];
context.setVariable('custom.resourceId', resourceId);
return;
}
let resourceId = context.getVariable('request.queryparam.'.concat(resourceIdPath));
context.setVariable('custom.resourceId', resourceId);
return;
}
```

just trying to get id either from pathvariable or queryparam in above logic

but with let keyword I m getting error that I have already pasted.

with var it is working fine.

Is let keyword of javascript is not supported in apigee ?

Comment: `let resourceId = context.getVariable('request.queryparam.'.concat(resourceIdPath));` I think you're missing a  `)`

Comment: possibly: `let resourceId = context.getVariable('request.queryparam').concat(resourceIdPath);` ?

Comment: You are right, the let keyword is not supported on Apigee. Reference - https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Apigee/What-version-of-JavaScript-is-available-to-JavaScript-callouts/m-p/12028/highlight/true#M8039. The post is a bit old. Current Rhino engine used in Apigee is of version 1.7.12 - https://docs.apigee.com/release/supported-software#apigeeedgecloud-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Sadly no.

url: https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Apigee/Is-let-keyword-of-javascript-not-supported-in-apigee/td-p/647957

Because of javascript version used by Agpigee.